# I got logged out of Fedora and received the following error: unexpected system error

Tags: linux, fedora

I randomly got logged out and then received this error:
[![Error][1]][1]

I use Fedora with the kernel: 6.2.12-300.fc38.x86_64

After I clicked on details I got this:

**reason**: traps: gnome-shell[3142] general protection fault ip:7f61a1a29d82 sp:7ffcbf7629d8 error:0 in memfd:libffi (deleted)[7f61a1a29000+1000]

**backtrace**: traps: gnome-shell[3142] general protection fault ip:7f61a1a29d82 sp:7ffcbf7629d8 error:0 in memfd:libffi (deleted)[7f61a1a29000+1000]

**cmdline**: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,gpt2)/vmlinuz-6.2.12-300.fc38.x86_64 root=UUID=f5e63bb8-3bd6-4858-a42e-b785ee4932c1 ro rootflags=subvol=root rd.luks.uuid=luks-26ec0013-1b37-4102-af44-4a5f4ea187bc rhgb quiet

**package**: kernel-core-6.2.12-300.fc38

**component**: kernel

**user**: unkown user

**OS release**: Fedora release 38 (Thirty Eight)

I don't know what to do it's an almost fresh install that's 2 days old.